# ubuntu server - what is process kssw?

Tags: server

On my ubuntu server, I have a kssw process that consumes 300% of my cpu.

Do you know what it is?

It does slow down all my installed web applications.

Thanks

Comment: Never heard of it. "sw" could be "swap".  "ksw" is VPN killswitch for networkmanager but that is not part of regular installation.  You probably installed it as part of some software but i have not found in online :)

Comment: Smells like a possible cryptominer.

Comment: `sudo lsof -c kssw`, `locate kssw` will start you finding out.